# Unable to join the translators chat

Tags: translation

The invite link for Slack at https://elementary.io/get-involved#translations does not work. It says:

> Please check with the person who shared it with you to see if there's a new link available.

Does anyone know who *the person* is and how to contact him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any issue related to the elementary.io website can be reported here: [Elementary OS website GitHub](https://github.com/elementary/website/issues). Your particular issue is already reported [here](https://github.com/elementary/website/issues/2255), and it seems to be caused by slack links expiring after a certain number of uses. I encourage you to contribute to that issue on github, and maybe ask for a working invite link there.